# Recursion in Java - print string permutations

Tags: java, loops, recursion, permutation

I'm trying to write a method that prints all of the permutations of a string using recursion. For now, I have this code that works:

```
private static void printPermutations(String in, String out) {
    if (in.length() == 0) System.out.println(out);
    else {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < in.length() ; i++) {
        printPermutations(in.substring(0, i) + in.substring(i + 1), out + in.charAt(i));
    }
    }
}
```

It prints the right result, but I'm trying to solve it without using loops at all, including the one in line 4. Is it possible? If so, how would you solve it? Thank you!

I tried to add a third parameter called index and write index+1 inside the recursive call in line 5 but it didn't work. I think adding the third parameter is a good idea, I'm just not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure why you are trying to do that.. this is kind of the setup you would be doing for recursion, you need to not return void otherwise it's not really recursion. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_recursion.asp) is a good resource.

> ```
>  public class Main {
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>     int result = sum(10);
>     System.out.println(result);
>   }
>   public static int sum(int k) {
>     if (k > 0) {
>       return k + sum(k - 1);
>     } else {
>       return 0;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

This would return something like

> ```
> 10 + sum(9)
> 10 + ( 9 + sum(8) )
> 10 + ( 9 + ( 8 + sum(7) ) )
> ...
> 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + sum(0)
> 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0
> ```

I hope that kind of helps you put together what you need. You have to have a return so the Recursive method can see its previous call, it takes information then like a rubberband once it reaches a certain point it returns all of your iterations. Personally, I like loops more, easier to read and easier to code.

An implementation for what you are trying to do would be:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = Variations("test");
    System.out.println(result);
  }
  public static String Variations(String k) {
    if (k.length() > 0) {
      return k + k.substring(0, k.lenth() - 1);
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
}
```

That would be the variation of what you are looking to do I believe.

Comment: The Reason something like this works is because when the length of whatever string you are trying to get permutations for gets to 0, the method no longer calls itself recursively. meanwhile the entire time result is getting all of the permutations added to it.

Comment: W3 Schools is a valid source, I linked it I am not passing this work as my own. their documentation is good and their explanations are good.

Comment: It really isn't, and just linking is not actually sufficient, you need to explicitly attribute. In addition, the license of w3schools doesn't allow you to copy it (though you might get away with using fair use as an excuse). In any case, I added quote blocks to that copied code so it is clear it isn't your own. However, I recommend you more clearly and explicitly state the source of that code.

Comment: roger that I was not trying to pass it as not my own. I am still learning the requirements of how to word responses, as I haven't used communities before... I have knowledge and am just trying to help people.